# Collapse z-scores from non-normal data?

Tags: z-score

I have a data set in which I want to combine 4 variables into one scale. The variables are open ended questions (e.g., How much would you be willing to pay for ...) and thus non-normally distributed. Usually, I would calculate z-scores and average across the variables to receive a single scale score. But does that also work with non-normal data? Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to create z-scores for non-normal data and count data, but the process really depends on what you are starting with and what you are trying to achieve.  A minimum working example (in this case of a normal data problem you have solved this way in the past as well as the data you are working with now) would really help in creating an answer for your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Sorry for providing too little detail. I have for different open ended questions, which measure the same construct, but of course have completely different response scales--one is measured in $US, one in minutes, one in number of blocks, and one in amount of weekdays (1-7). Basically, what I am not certain about is what the best way would be to calculate a composite measure of these items.

Comment: 1.
Just sum them up and take the average? That would easy to interpret, yet the SD's of each item differ considerably, perhaps making the measure less reliable. What do you think?
2.
Calculate z-scores, sum them up and take the average? This is what I would do if I had different Likert scales (e.g., 1-7 vs. 1-5). But in this case the residuals for each item are non-normally distributed, which makes we wonder if I still get reliable outcomes if I standardize them, combine them and calculate the mean. Hope this makes it clearer. Thanks very much for your help.